# How to install Rufus on Ubuntu Mate?

Tags: rufus

I have been to the website & while there is talk of it being compatible there is no actual Linux supported link for it, its all exe's. I am using Ubuntu Mate the latest version 64Bit edition.

If someone can provide a direct link or terminal code to make it happen because its not showing up under the software center even with 3rd party enabled.

Comment: Rufus is a tool for creating bootable media, such a creating a bootable USB or DVD for installing Ubuntu.  Ubuntu is a very friendly environment.  You can use it for many things.  Once you boot it up, you can easily go to the software center and find games that run on Ubuntu.  You can also find many other tools such as word processors, accounting programs, or just about anything else you would use a computer for.  If Windows games are what you are looking to run, either use the Windows OS or a Windows emulator such as Wine on Linux.  Can you tell us what you are trying to do with Rufus?

Comment: Downvoted - does not show research effort: The [Rufus website](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) is very clear that Rufus is Windows-only software. It can burn *any* ISO, including Linux ISOs, but those are just payloads.

Answer (score 10):

**Rufus app is available for Windows platform only.**

But you can use other softwares like `winusb`, `dd`, `unetbootin`, ....

Here is short `dd` tutorial for making bootable drives :

Plug in the USB flash drive and determine the device it's mounted on with the command:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

This time around it was `/dev/sdc1` for me, so I'll use that as my example.

Unmount the device

```
umount /dev/sdc1
```

The next step is to copy the iso. Copy to the device not partition (i.e copy to `sdc` not `sdc1`) as shown below:

```
sudo dd if=filename.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=4M
```

Perform final steps :

```
sync   
sudo eject /dev/sdc
```

That's all . :)

[Source](https://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-get-the-Rufus-app-for-Ubuntu-How-can-I-install-it)

Comment: Rufus states on its site that it is compatible with Linux. And if not I will just reinstall Windows & use it on there. I dont want to use alternatives. I really wish Linux were more user friendly & supported more games & content.

Comment: Yes, it is compatible with making Linux bootable devices on Windows, but it won't run on Linux itself. :(

Comment: However, you can use `wine` to play windows games. People say that, some games play better than Windows itself using `wine`. And there is steam app on linux if you are interested

Comment: Guess ill install Windows on the server then I need Rufus all the other alternatives I have tried failed miserably. And sadly I am quite stupid when it comes to linux, and I have not used dos in so many years most of those commands are lot to me.

Comment: Have you tried `winusb`? I think you have not...